# Users are able to find my origins IP via Censys

Tags: security, ssl, cloudflare, ddos

How are users able to find the IP of my origin servers using a tool like Censys.io- I'm using cloudflare and have recently suffered a DDoS attack.

I've been looking up some other sites on this service and was able to find some IPs as well. How can I prevent this from happening? I've been trying to find a solution to this but I can't really think of the right terms.

Comment: Well there is not much that can be done but some best practices can provide you some protection . This article outlines some of the approaches and some best practices which can help you ....https://www.secjuice.com/finding-real-ips-of-origin-servers-behind-cloudflare-or-tor/

Comment: if you are using AWS consider load balance.

Comment: Maybe your services are configured to reply as its ServerName, execute ``nikto -host http://example.com`` or ``curl -vvvv http://example.com`` and see what information does give you and the http options/headers

Comment: @EduardoGonzalez when executing this it returns the IP from cloudflare as it should.